# Throttling network for other applications

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, network-programming

A friend likes to limit his applications to a use a certain bandwidth-limit. Seen as he doesn't have the widest connection and - for example - not every application that downloads/uploads has the ability to throttle/limit their downloads/uploads (Like Steam or a torrent downloader.). So he was wondering if I could maybe put something together since I fiddle around with WinForms often. I recommended [NetLimiter](https://www.netlimiter.com/) and [NetBalancer](https://netbalancer.com/), but I was curious as to whether I could make this in C# myself.

I have searched the web and found some decent solutions as to throttling in an application itself but as to throttling applications outside of the current application you have the source code of, I haven't been able to find anything that would help me understand how to program this from scratch.

Do any of you know how I'd go about throttling other applications? Would I have to write my own network interface and have Windows reroute traffic through that?

Thank you for your time.

EDIT: Seen as the first comment tells me I'm at the wrong address with C#, I [rephrased my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41840398) in the hopes of a better way to get an answer.

Comment: AFAIK you'd implement that as a NDIS Network Filter Driver, but you can't use managed code for that as it runs in the kernel. Explaining how to write such a driver would hence be too broad, and I think your friend is better of setting up proper QoS in either their OS or their router.