# Writing drivers for Windows

Tags: c++, windows, networking, driver

I recently asked [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41825256) if I could limit bandwidth via a C# WinForms applications much like NetLimiter and NetBalancer. I was told that there's two ways to do this. Either via proper [QoS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374094(v=vs.85).aspx) or writing something along the lines of an "[NDIS Network Filter Driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/network/ndis-filter-drivers)". Using QoS isn't the way I want to take. So I've looked up some of the stuff required to write drivers and found some interesting points. Points such as a good understanding of C/C++, because the executed code being very prone to BSODs since it could be run in something called "Kernel mode". I also found a GitHub "[dump](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/network/ndis/filter)" which looks interesting and tempts me to investigate and look around in.

As you can see I'm no where near advanced enough to delve into this on a professional level. Ignoring that, what would be a good start to start my adventures into writing drivers to monitor - and further down the line  manipulate the network to introduce throttling.

Any help, guides or information that might be of help is always appreciated.

PS: I am unsure as to whether this is (as afore mentioned in a comment to my previous question) too broad a question to be answered on Stack Overflow. If so, where would I go to ask this?

Comment: This seems too broad (and off-topic with the tutorial/guide ask) to me. You could go to a more traditional forum, try to find a tutor/mentor, or if it were me, start writing something based on what you have already found and ask *specific* questions about it here.

Comment: Where would I find a tutor/mentor for this, though, @BradleyDotNET. Is there a form where I can sign up to? And I have found something of which I understand little, hence why I included it. Though it might've been better if I started off with that.

Comment: Pluralsight has a mentor/help program, I'm sure there are others. Vilx's advice is the path I would start with at least though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, this would be too broad. Driver writing is a complicated thing which requires a good understanding of how a computer and the OS works. Also, C# (and .NET itself) indeed isn't available in Kernel Mode, so C/C++ is the preferred way. Although theoretically any unmanaged language (like Pascal) could do, I haven't heard of anyone writing drivers in them. Microsoft's own developer resources are also written with C/C++ in mind.

Which brings us to the question of *why* you want to do it.

If you need it for work and there's a deadline - forget it. Get someone else who already knows this stuff. Or there might be a library out there that fills the need. Any of these options will be cheaper than your time spent learning all this stuff.

If it's for your own curiosity however - go for it! I'd advise by starting to learn C first. Not C++, that's more complicated and for drivers it will be easier with C anyway. But you can pick up C++ later too, it's good stuff. C++ is *mostly* compatible with C, so you can start with C and then continue with C++.

In parallel, get a good book about OS design. Not because you want to design an OS, but to understand the basic concepts that it is built upon. You should get a good understanding of things such as Kernel Mode/User Mode, virtual memory, interrupts, process scheduling, etc.

Learning a bit of assembly might be useful too (albeit not required).

Finally, when you feel like you've got a good grasp of the above, head over to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/index) and start reading about driver development. There will be long articles and example programs to get you started. Tweak them and play around in a virtual machine until you get what you need.

And also... read [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20140214100538/http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mickens/thenightwatch.pdf).